# How to change progress bar and textbox from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I've built an installer script for some software. I'm trying to make to such that my installation script (InstallationScript.cs) and Form GUI (Install.cs) are partitioned. However, when I try to update the form components from the InstallationScript class, it `cannot resolve symbol`, but yet can see methods like `.Show()`. I thought perhaps if I exposed a public reference to itself it would be able to see the instance of the form, but that doesn't seem to work either. Am I missing something here?

```
namespace Generic_Installer_Framework.gui {
    public partial class Install : Form {
       public static Install Self;

        public Install() {
            Self = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void InstallStep(int value, string message, string logMessage = "") {
            Logger.Log(logMessage == "" ? message : logMessage);

            installationProgressBar.Value = value;
            installationRichTextBox.AppendText(message + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Other class:

```
namespace Generic_Installer_Framework{
    class InstallationScript {
        private readonly Form _installerForm = Install.Self;

        public void Start() {

            //This works
            _installerForm.Show();

            //This doesn't
            _installerForm.InstallStep(0, "Starting...");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Where is InitializeComponents() method ?

Comment: @Fabjan, I removed it when I was cleaning up the constructor to post here. I'll re-add it. Apologies!

Comment: Ha.  I read, "I've built an interstellar script...."

Comment: @jrahhali: LOL! I would never describe my code as interstellar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, when I try to update the form components from the
>   InstallationScript class, it cannot resolve symbol, but yet can see
>   methods like .Show().

The problem is right here:

```
private readonly Form _installerForm = Install.Self;
```

You've declared "_installerForm" as the generic type of `Form`, which of course has no idea what you're talking about...

Change the type to `Install`, and all should be good:

```
private readonly Install _installerForm = Install.Self;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

My guess that it can be because you run Start() method in a different Thread. You can try to pass this method inside a delegate :

```
public Action<int, string, string> InsStep = new Action<int, string, string>(InstallStep);
```

Try to call it in your InstallationScript class by `installerForm.InsStep(0, "Starting...", "");`

You can also benefit from using SynchronizationContext.Current property:
First you take it from your form :

```
SynchronizationContext sync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

Then you pass it to another Thread or whereever you want and use like:

```
sync.Post(delegate 
{
    // your updates here will be executed thread-safe
}, null);
```